# RubyMine doesn't recognize `it_behaves_like` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

When I open a spec like `it_behaves_like` method is not recognized by RubyMine with error message `can't find 'it_behaves_like'`.

The RSpec test itself works fine, so somehow RubyMine can't find the method.

In the Preference `rspec-rails` is listed.[image]

How can I find where the problem stand?

### Edit

It seems `RubyMine` can't recognize dynamically defined method.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13950

Comment: Time revealed thar RubyMine isn't a perfect tool, when it concerns so-called "spell checking". It constantly can't find words that are defined for certain, especially the dynamically generated ones (which is not your case). Does it only complain or it does not allow to run tests from GUI?

Comment: I'm running test by `guard` in another terminal so the RSpec test works fine. I just want to remove unnecessary warnings.

Comment: I replace _underscores with spaces, and then RM does find it. So, what happens when you search for  `it behaves like`  ?

Comment: @Mauddev In your way RubyMine recognize the "words" not the "method".

Comment: O yes, true, that's something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, RubyMine, even latest version has a problem recognising these generated methods. You have the option of "tricking" RubyMine into recognising it though. Simply add the following empty method to the end of your spec_helper.rb:

```
def it_behaves_like(*args) ; end
```

This will make RubyMine see a method with the correct signature,  but it will still be overriden by rspec, so it will not affect your tests.

Even better, you can put it in a require from spec_helper.rb, e.g. rubymine_signatures.rb

```
require 'rubymine_signatures'
```

No matter where it is placed, however, it will still be polluting your codebase to 'fix' the IDE, which I don't recommend doing. Since it is only for tests though, it can be defended.